# Split the texts in the array into words Python

Tags: python, xml-parsing, separator

Is there a way to split the text of each input in an array to words with a separator?
Example Input

```
tag_attribute = ['Content_ExportDate','Controller_SoftwareRevision','DataType_Owner']
```

With the separator as '_', the expected printed result:

```
Tag: Content
Attribute: Exportdate
Tag: Controller
Attribute: SoftwareRevision
Tag: DataType
Attribute: Owner
```

The '_' is just an example I can think of for a separator, but I can work with any of other symbols. I just need to find a way to have the input in an array as two separate inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this example it will generate you the output that you want

```
for tag, att in [x.split("_") for x in tag_attribute]:
  print(f"Tag: {tag}")
  print(f"Attribute: {att}")
```